# Finding time complexity of a recursion code

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

The code is written in **Java**. Here, I am **reversing an integer array using recursion.**

I am unable to find the time complexity of the below code:

```
class Test2 {
    public static int[] reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            int temp;
            temp = arr[start];
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;

            reverse(arr, start + 1, end - 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] value = reverse(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(value[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, please provide an explanation of the time complexity solution, if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: It's O(n). The number of swaps is directly proportional to the size of the array.

Comment: @shmosel Could you please elaborate on your response? I am unable to understand. The size of the array is 5. how is the size proportional to the number of swaps?

Comment: How many swaps are required for size 5? How many for 10? How many for 50? How many for 100? Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You code complexity is O(N). Recursion here can be confusing, but in fact, it can be easily converted to the following code without any recursion:

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int i=0;
    int j=arr.length-1;
    for ( ;i<j; ) {
        int temp;
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

}

This is the same algorithm as yours. You need only N/2 loop iterations.